# Run soap-ui mockservicerunner as a non-blocking process

Tags: linux, web-services, soapui

I use soap-ui to run a webservice mock on a linux system. 
The linux call looks like this

`/opt/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.4.0/bin/mockservicerunner.sh ./test-soapui-project.xml`

I don't manage to run the mock as a process. when I do the following, the "Press any key to terminate" still appears.

`/opt/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.4.0/bin/mockservicerunner.sh ./test-soapui-project.xml &`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a SoapUI issue, but rather a unix/linux issue.

A quick google makes me think this tread covers the issue...?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266565/daemonize-a-process-in-shell